# mod rewrite - allow full stops 

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a rewrite rule that allows full stops.  How can I allow for this? What I want is for 
shop/domain/www.test.com to become shop/domain/controller.php?param1=www.test.com

The original rule I have is below:

RewriteRule ^shop/domain/([^/.]+)/?$ shop/stock/controller.php?param1=$1 [NC]

This works but only if I remove the full stop.

I have also tried the following:

RewriteRule ^shop/domain/([^/]+)/?$ shop/domain/controller.php?param1=$1 [NC]

This allows the full stop but then has controller.php is the parameter when it should be www.test.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all domains begin with "www.", you could do this

```
RewriteRule ^shop/domain/www\.([^/]+)/?$ shop/domain/controller.php?param1=$1 [NC,L]
```

The problem with your rule is, that it also matches `controller.php` as if it were a domain. You can add the following two rewrite conditions to prevent this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^shop/domain/([^/]+)/?$ shop/domain/controller.php?param1=$1 [NC,L]
```

`!-d` means not an existing directory, `!-f` means not an exisiting file (e.g. `controller.php`).

Comment: yes that works, thanks.  What if I do not want the "www."?  I dont undertsand how it works if I include the www. and doesn't work when I leave it out.

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Please consider accepting this answer. Good luck with your shop!